Why my navbar revert back to older version after saving in dawn theme Shopify?
I change the navbar to newly created one but as I save it, it revert back to older version and I don't see that one in navigation also. I am not sure from where those menus comes from.
(This is the default navbar)
I want change navbar to newly created navbar This navbar I want to display...
you can see in the screenshot I already selected in the customizer but still not showing. I already selected this one but after saving it remain selected but on frontend it revert back to older version
